# Trouble accessing Global VAR in While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, global-variables

Sorry, this was a dumb question. The solutions are correct for using global variables, but there was just something else wrong with my code.

Here's a snippet of the code. I'm working on Problem 3/Problem Set 2 form the 6.00x MIT course.

```
paymentFound = False

while paymentFound == False:
    global paymentFound
    testMid = findMid(newMin, newMax)
    testStatus = testPayment(testMid)
    if testStatus == "done":
        paymentFound = True
        print "Lowest Payment: ",testMid
    elif testStatus == "high":
        newMax = testMid
    elif testStatus == "low":
        newMin = testMid
```

This is the error that I'm getting: 
pset1.3.py:32: SyntaxWarning: name 'paymentFound' is assigned to before global declaration
  global paymentFound

I read somewhere that you can't use global variables if they're important to a 'for' loop, but I don't know if this is important in a while loop.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this error?

Sorry, had to reedit the code so it looks more presentable.

Comment: Why do you want `paymentFound` to be global?  If this code snippet is from a function `paymentFound` should probably be local, not global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is described by the error message: Your "global" command is too late. Try this:

```
global paymentFound
paymentFound = False

while paymentFound == False:
    testMid = findMid(newMin, newMax)
    ...
```

Comment: The problem persists. In the if statement, when I reset paymentFound to true, that only sets the value of a local variable also called paymentFound.

Comment: I need to somehow access the global variable 'paymentFound' within the while loop.

Comment: "*In the if statement, when I reset paymentFound to true, that only sets the value of a local variable*" - Respectfully, [I don't believe you.](http://ideone.com/2ED5vS). Perhaps you could reduce your program to the smallest complete program that demonstrates the error, and paste that program into your question. See http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you should 'global' it out of the loop like this:

```
global paymentFound
paymentFound = False

while ~:
    yourcode
```

i happen to meet this problem before.

i tried this codes and it did work:

```
global a 
a = 1

while a :
    if True:
        a = 0
    print('is it?')
```